# Algorithm to extract 2 levels down

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

Hi guys i have the following string

```
&|L1|L2|L3|&
```

I would like to extract L1 out and do some if statement to it. Meaning i would have to read for each `& &` and `| |` then extract L1?

THanks for your help!

THe string is not fixed `>.<`  sometimes its 
`&|L1|A2|A3|& %3123%`

Comment: Do you always only need L1? or do you want a list of all the Ls?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want result string without L1,l2,l3 etc ? Or do you want string with only L1,l2,l3 etc  ? Will levels always comes in pipe ( like this |L1|) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check by looping the each char or all the chars at a time. See the below code

```
            string Str = "&|L1|L2|L3|&";
            for(int i= 0;i<Str.Length;i++)
            {
                if (Str[i] == 'L' && Str[i+1] == '1')
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Str[i].ToString() + Str[i+1].ToString() + " Found");
                }
            }
```

Comment: But my actual string always changes and the number of L1 L2 L3 always changes ><

Comment: If how many times it changes, the above code will pick out only the L1 string from the actual string. Try it once.

Comment: Who is the bloody, to downvote with out giving a single reason. What is wrong in it?

Answer (score 3):

If you know your data is always formatted like this, and you always want the substring contained between the first and second pipe characters, a simple regex will work (this is in C#, as that's what you've tagged the question with):

```
string testString = "&|L1|L2|L3|&";
string match = Regex.Match(testString, @"^.+?\|(.+?)\|").Groups[1].Value;
```

You can then perform whatever logic you need to on "match". Regex explanation: match the start of the string followed by a lazy match of any characters up to the first pipe, lazy match and capture any characters up to the next pipe.